# Conditional routing in to the Angular application

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have an existing Angular App using `ui.router` wherein multiple states are being internally called from one another. The initial state is directed using $urlRouterProvider as :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/initial');
```

Authentications are then made in this initial state and application flow starts.

Now, the user want to directly see a particular screen based on some Id parameters. To explain, now the user directly wants to open `http://domain/stateC/12`. This link should open from some hyperlink in an excel file.

My question now is how can I check the condition whether which url is entered in to the address bar and based on that if the url is matching pattern like`http://domain/stateC/12` then I can redirect to state `stateC` else to state `initial`. Basically I am looking to make some condition in my `app.config` module based on the incoming URL to the application.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: you can add one service function in resolve of route configuration and if it is not authorized then redirect to login page

Comment: how about using [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)? you can catch a 404 and redirect to login state

Comment: Well that will work, but since this is an existing application; I am looking for the shortest possible method. Something like a check somwehere